# Get 'mouse over object' on LWJGL/OpenGL?

Tags: java, opengl, vector, lwjgl, collision

I'm developing a 'block-based game' (something like Minecraft), and I got stuck on one thing:

Supposing I have control of everything in the world (blocks and entities), and every one of them has an AABB (location, size, etc)... how could I get what my mouse is looking/pointing at? The player has a rotation system according to mouse movements. I just don't know how to get the block/entity I'm looking at.

Comment: What type of data structure are you using for all the information?

Comment: I'm sorry, but my native language isn't english so I don't know if I understand your question... but, I'm storing all world blocks into a List<Block>, and all entities into a List<Entity>. Every Block and Entity has a AABB, which contains the location and size (bounds) of the block/entity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can to use a form of [ray casting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ray_casting) from your eye vector. Basically extend that ray to the distance you want to be able to consider within reach of your player and then test the intersection of that ray with the nearby blocks. The block with the closest intersection should be the one you are focused on.

To test the intersection of that ray with the blocks, you'll need to check it against each plane on the block. You can use a ray-plane intersection algorithm to accomplish that.

Obviously, try to reduce the number of blocks and planes you test against as much as possible to increase the performance.

Comment: Thank you! I'm gonna take a look on it.

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively to Marc's variant, you can use picking by color. To do this you need the following steps:

1) Turn off lighting, blending, multisampling, texturing and so on. If you use shaders, just set up the simplest shader program (it should be prepared so that you only need one `glUseProgram` call), which only transforms your geometry and renders each part of it with specified color. Don't turn off z-buffer!

2) Render your scene to an offscreen buffer with all transformations applied. Each item you want to distinguish should have it's own color. If you have 8 bits per each of 3 color channels, then you will be able to select among 2^(3*8)=16777216 items.

3) Pick the color value from the offscreen buffer at the point of your interest, i.e. at the window coordinates of the mouse pointer. At the 1st step we didn't turn off z-buffer, so you will get the color of the nearest object pointed by mouse.

4) Reset render state (turn on multisampling, choose proper shader or turn on lighting and other effects) and render the scene to the window buffer.

To my mind, this technique is much easier to implement then raycasting, because you only adjust the state of your renderer and the hardware performs all the hard work.

Performance of this technique is increased automatically when you increase performance of your regular render by using [frustum culling](http://www.lighthouse3d.com/tutorials/view-frustum-culling/), [octree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octree), [bsp](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_space_partitioning) and so on.

More about framebuffer objects:

- http://www.songho.ca/opengl/gl_fbo.html
- http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Framebuffer_Object

Topics about color picking:

- [Color coded picking problem in OpenGL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4550350/color-coded-picking-problem-in-opengl)
- http://www.lighthouse3d.com/opengl/picking/index.php3?color1
- [Color picking in the openGL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8780871/color-picking-in-the-opengl)

I'm sure you can find more tutorials about color-coded picking in google.

Comment: +1 @Sergey This is an interesting technique I hadn't thought of. I assume you'd still need to compute the distance from the player to the object picked. The only thing I'm not sure about is what if the object is only partially within a distance to pick? With ray casting, we can find the exact intersection of the plane and determine if that's a valid distance. Is that simple with this technique? I assume you'd have to color each pixel on a box to achieve this. Regardless, if it can be done on hardware, that's obviously a plus.

Comment: Also, depending on where you're doing the frustum culling, etc. you could do the ray casting after as well, but regardless this is an interesting technique to achieve this.

Comment: @Marc Baumbach I have never tried to determine distance with this technique, but I suppose it's possible. The idea is that after an item was picked, we can render only that mesh (or only that polygon, if possible) to an offscreen buffer with another type of shader. That shader should add fog (linear of distance) or simply transmit `gl_FragCoord.w` (which is usually interpolated `-1/z`, where `z` is `z` from `gl_Position` of vertex shader) to the buffer. Depth component of the buffer should be the most suitable for that.

Comment: So we can read the depth component and restore `z`. Knowing `z` and position (with rotation) of the camera it should be possible to restore distance and exact intersection. Maybe it will be better to pass more information to fragment shader (via uniforms) and perform more computations on GPU. Anyway, it's just a sketch of the algorithm and it needs elaboration.

Comment: Yea, that's what I figured. Again, +1 on the idea, I certainly think it'd be a good approach to keep everything in hardware.